# Python AIML error

Tags: python, aiml

I'm starting a project with Python which uses AIML, when I run the script It gives me a 'Not match found' error. This is the Python code:

```
import aiml
kernel = aiml.Kernel()
kernel.learn("bot.aiml")
while True:
    print kernel.respond(raw_input("\n>>"))
```

Just a simple AIML kernel. Is it something wrong with it?

Comment: What's in the `bot.aiml` file?

Answer (score 0):

I have a better python script if you are interested

```
import aiml
import sys <br>

brainLoaded = False
forceReload = False
while not brainLoaded:
    if forceReload or (len(sys.argv) >= 2 and sys.argv[1] == "reload"):

        kern.bootstrap(learnFiles="Database.xml", commands="load aiml b")
        brainLoaded = True
        kern.saveBrain("Cache.brn")
    else:
        # Attempt to load the brain file.  If it fails, fall back on the Reload
        try:
            # It is our cache file.
            kern.bootstrap(brainFile = "Cache.brn")
            brainLoaded = True
        except:
            forceReload = True

# Enter the main input/output loop.
print "Enter your message for the chatbot"
while(True):
    print kern.respond(raw_input("> "))
```

Note: You need to create a folder Database where you place your AIML files
and a file Database.xml

Answer (score 0):

"No match found for input" warning occurs because because "bot.aiml" doesn't have a matching output for your input. Try to include a default response like the following:

```
<category>
    <pattern>*</pattern>
    <template>
        Sorry. I didn't quite get that.
    </template>
</category>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Removing the 'print' statement in the code

```
import aiml
kernel = aiml.Kernel()
kernel.learn("bot.aiml")
while True:
     kernel.respond(raw_input("\n>>"))
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to write the sentence in ***.aiml*** in capital letter into the `<pattern>` tag. But you can put your input both in smaller letter and capital letter. Otherwise you will get the error like that. For example:

```
<category>
    <pattern>WHAT IS YOUR NAME ?</pattern>
    <template>My name is robot.</template>
</category
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, if anyone needs it for Python 3 what should be done is just a change in the syntax of the **print** function. In python2 it accepts the function without parentheses, but in python3 it is mandatory to use it.

Another observation is that the **raw_input()** function has been renamed to **input()** in python3.

So the solution to resolve this syntax error is quite simple:

```
while True:
    print(kernel.respond(input("\n>>")))
```

We added the parentheses to the **print** function including the content to be displayed and started to use the **input()** function, since there is no more **raw_input()** in python3.